# CC License: Attribute xmlns:dct not allowed here

Tags: html, xml

I'm working on a [simple real estate website](http://www.bangalore-property-buy.com/real-estate/property-for-sale/lang/cn/index.html) The W3C validator gives me the following error, on a cut and paste Creative Commons license:

```
 Error Line 121, Column 279: *Attribute xmlns:dct not allowed here.*

…rl.org/dc/terms/" property="dct:title">Bangalore Property Buy</span> by <a xml…

Warning Line 121, Column 279: *Attribute with the local name xmlns:dct is not serializable as XML 1.0.*

…rl.org/dc/terms/" property="dct:title">Bangalore Property Buy</span> by <a xml…

Error Line 121, Column 457: *Attribute xmlns:cc not allowed here.*

…tributionName" rel="cc:attributionURL">IndiranagarSeller@-ignore-this-gmail.co…

Warning Line 121, Column 457: *Attribute with the local name xmlns:cc is not serializable as XML 1.0.*

…tributionName" rel="cc:attributionURL">IndiranagarSeller@-ignore-this-gmail.co…
```

How can I fix this and what do the errors mean?

Comment: I noticed that the URL "http://www.bangalore-property-buy.com/real-estate/property-for-sale/lang/cn/index.html" is dead. What is a "real estate website"? Sorry for my curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to XHTML and change your `DOCTYPE` to use the DTD for [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).

Your HTML document will then start with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

However, you will likely run into further validation issues to be resolved if you make this change.

Comment: @AlexanderUlyanov you'd be best off asking a new question about your particular validation problems providing example code that you're trying to get working. This answer might not be applicable to your scenario, and even if it is, there are likely additional changes that will be needed to make it validate as XHTML.

Comment: 4 softwariness: Why new question? I have the same question and problem. My page: http://tuchkovo-auto.ru/

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov A new question because you have your own set of validation problems. The above answer may or may not be part of the solution to your set of problems, but even if it is, there will likely be other things to resolve. Creating a new question is your best bet for getting an answer to your questions, and your question should provide the information needed about your specific problems within it, not a link to your website.

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov the above doctype is not W3C compliant. The W3C validator says it's "legacy" now.