# Machine-readable metadata autogenerated by Creative Commons (CC) not W3C-compliant

Tags: html, xml-namespaces, w3c-validation, cc

I added a CC license to my website using the [Choose a License tool](https://creativecommons.org/choose/#metadata) hosted by CC:

`<a rel="license" target="_blank" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by/4.0/88x31.png"></a><br>This work by <a xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" href="https://example.com" property="cc:attributionName" rel="cc:attributionURL">[My Name]</a> is licensed under a <a rel="license" target="_blank" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License</a>`

A [W3C validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CelianRiboulet.webvalidator) marked the anchor as invalid because "Attribute 'xmlns:cc' not allowed here." **How can I use the machine-readable metadata in my license anchor while still keeping the website W3C-compliant?**

I tried the solution posted as a response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134385/cc-license-attribute-xmlnsdct-not-allowed-here) asked eight years ago, but the solution given either never was or is no longer W3C-compliant.